# in our Java applet, why is init() being called repeatedly?

Tags: java, applet, initialization

I'm working on the code for a game written in Java that runs as both an application and an applet. When we run the game as an applet from a browser, we see that in some cases init() is getting called repeatedly during the game -- two or three or four times. We've put in some debugging code that seems to clearly demonstrate that is the case --inside init() we increment a variable every time that init() is called. It's my impression that this should NEVER happen, yet it seems to be, and it's clearly not restricted to one OS. Am I overlooking something obvious? If not, do you have any ideas on how this could happen?

I'm using Swing and MigLayout, and editing the code with Eclipse.

MORE INFO:
I don't have permission to post any significant pieces of the code. But to give slightly more context, init() is called by the main class of the applet. The init() code is like this:

```
    Container cpane; 
    boolean inAnApplet = true;
    public void init(Container c)
     {
      cPane = c;
      init();
     }
    public void init()
     {
      if (inAnApplet)
       cPane = getContentPane();
      // more code goes here, 
      // and then
      if (inAnApplet)
       initConnection();
    }
```

Suppose the main class is named BigGuy, then the structure of the code of the main class is that if the software is run as an applet in a Web page, it of course runs init().

And if the software is instead run as an application, BigGuy.main() does stuff like this:

```
inAnApplet = false;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
BigGuy theApp = new BigGuy();
frame.addWindowListener(theApp);
theApp.init(frame.getContentPane());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
theApp.input.requestFocusInWindow();
theApp.initConnection();
```

Comment: Your question is very vague. We do not have access to your code, so we don`t even know why this method is be called, by which method, and in which context. If you can provide the code, we`ll be able to provide more help.

Comment: `init()` should only be called once by the environment, but that doesn't stop it from being called by your own code. Are you sure you aren't calling it explicitly? - we can't tell since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. I added a bit of code.

Comment: Oops, I had included one line of code that was mistaken, so now I've removed it.

Comment: I edited the code again slightly one more time, for clarity

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).